# Boolean if statement being ignored?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I don't understand why the if statements in the final method are being ignored. Is it because I used too many if statements?

I've commented out all the if statements and tried using this code in printShowChosen(....) to see if the boolean values are actually carried over

```
System.out.println(showchosen[0]);
System.out.println(showchosen[1]);
System.out.println(showchosen[2]);
System.out.println(showchosen[3]);
```

And it printed out

```
true
false
false
true
```

Can someone explain where I went wrong?

Here is the complete code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class short8 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] ShowName = {"Les Miserables","Mamma Mia","Cats", "Chicago", "Phantom of the Opera"};
    String[] TheatreName = {"Queens Theatre", "Garrick Theatre", "Palmer Theatre", "Spoa Theatre", "Dend Theatre"};
    boolean[] showchosen = new boolean [5];

    askTouristChoices(TheatreName, showchosen);
    printShowsChosen(ShowName, TheatreName, showchosen);
    }//ends main

    public static String askTouristChoices(String[] ShowName, boolean[] showchosen)
    {
        System.out.println("Please type yes if you are interested in any of the following shows:");
        String interestedMiserables = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Les Miserables");
        String interestedMammaMia = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mamma Mia");
        String interestedCats = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cats");
        String interestedChicago = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Chicago");
        String interestedPhantom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Phantom of the Opera");


    if ((interestedMiserables.equals("Yes")) || (interestedMiserables.equals("yes")))
    {
        showchosen[0] = true;

    }
    else if ((interestedMiserables.equals("No")) || (interestedMiserables.equals("no")))
    {
        showchosen[0] = false;
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter either Yes or No!!");
    }

        if ((interestedMammaMia.equals("Yes")) || (interestedMammaMia.equals("yes")))
        {
            showchosen[1] = true;

        }
        else if ((interestedMammaMia.equals("No")) || (interestedMammaMia.equals("no")))
        {
            showchosen[1] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter either Yes or No!!");
        }

            if ((interestedCats.equals("Yes")) || (interestedCats.equals("yes")))
            {
                showchosen[2] = true;
            }
            else if ((interestedCats.equals("No")) || (interestedCats.equals("no")))
            {
                showchosen[2] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter either Yes or No!!");
            }

                if ((interestedChicago.equals("Yes")) || (interestedChicago.equals("yes")))
                {
                    showchosen[3] = true;
                }
                else if ((interestedChicago.equals("No")) || (interestedChicago.equals("no")))
                {
                    showchosen[3] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter either Yes or No!!");
                }

            if ((interestedPhantom.equals("Yes")) || (interestedPhantom.equals("yes")))
            {
                showchosen[4] = true;
            }
            else if ((interestedPhantom.equals("No")) || (interestedPhantom.equals("no")))
            {
                showchosen[4] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter either Yes or No!!");
            }

        return null;
    } //ends askTouristChoices

        public static void printShowsChosen(String[] ShowName,String[] TheatreName, boolean[] showchosen)
        {
            if(showchosen[0] = true)
            {
                System.out.println(ShowName[0] + ": " + TheatreName[0]);
            }

            if(showchosen[1] = true)
            {
                System.out.println(ShowName[1] + ": " + TheatreName[1]);
            }

            if(showchosen[2] = true)
            {
                System.out.println(ShowName[2] + ": " + TheatreName[2]);
            }

            if(showchosen[3] = true)
            {
                System.out.println(ShowName[3] + ": " + TheatreName[3]);
            }

            if(showchosen[4] = true)
            {
                System.out.println(ShowName[4] + ": " + TheatreName[4]);
            } 
        }//ends printShowsChosen    


}//ends short8
```

Comment: `if(showchosen[0] = true)` should be `if(showchosen[0] == true)` or more simple `if(showchosen[0])`. Same for the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
if(showchosen[0] = true)
```

should read

```
if(showchosen[0] == true)
```

or

```
if(showchosen[0])
```

A single `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
if(showchosen[0] = true)
```

should be:

```
if(showchosen[0] == true)
```

or even better:

```
if(showchosen[0])
```